# php.exe crashes on Windows (Faulting application php.exe, version 5.3.8.0)

Tags: php, windows, xampp, ntdll

I'm using **XAMPP version 1.7.7  on Windows Server Enterprise (32 bit)**.

I have setup some task in Task Schedule for background php scripts. It runs every after 3 minutes. Sometimes, it crashes and via event viewer we receive this information:

```
Faulting application php.exe, version 5.3.8.0, time stamp 0x4e53793f, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 6.0.6002.18881, time stamp 0x51da3e27, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x0003dd6d, process id 0xb88, application start time 0x01d039def0f42f10.
```

I have no idea why it crashes sometimes, most of the time it runs very well. There is no error or problem in the scripts either.

Is there anything I need to care in this regard ?

Thanks

Comment: Tried setting cron jobs instead of task schedules?

Comment: @Forien On Windows we can only have Task Schedulers which work like Cron Job right ? or I didn't get your point ?

Comment: @Arfeen correct. Task scheduler is all there is on stock windows

Answer (score 1):

You might want to update your PHP installation. The last available build of 5.3 seems to be 5.3.29 [PHP download archive](http://php.net/releases/). If there is nothing more in the event viewer log, the reason will be very hard to track.

If you are ready to make the switch to an even newer PHP version, I suggest thinking about IIS as an webserver. You can install the PHP versions using Microsoft's Web Platform Installer. Never had any problems with the PHP versions bundled with it.